# Why does this Python code give me the wrong answer?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I wrote a simple Python code to solve a certain Hydraulic formula (The [Manning's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manning_formula)):

```
import math

def mannings(units,A,P,S,n):
    if units=='SI':
        k=1.0
    elif units=='US':
        k=1.49
    R=A/P
    V=(k/n)*(math.pow(R,(2/3)))*(math.sqrt(S))
    Q=A*V
    return R,V,Q
```

In the code above, the velocity `V` is calculated from the `k`, `n`, `R` and `S`. The velocity is then used to calculate the discharge `Q` by multiplying with Area `A`. The user inputs the unit convention, the `A`, `P`, `S` and `n`. `k` is decided on the basis of unit convention.

When I run the function using `mannings('US',1.0618,2.7916,0.02,0.015)`, I get `(0.38035535176959456, 14.047854719572745, 14.916012141242343)`. The `R` value matches the `R` calculated in a spreadsheet, but the `V` and `Q` are way off. The actual `V` should be `7.374638178`
and the `Q` should be `7.830634155`.

It'd be great if someone can tell me what's going wrong here. This is a pretty straightforward formula and I was guessing it should work easily.

Comment: Just on side note: Maybe `k / n * R ** (2.0 / 3) * S ** .5` is more legible than spelling out `math.pow` and `math.swrt`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that `2/3` is an integer division and therefore evaluates to `0`. You want `2.0/3` to force a floating-point division. Or else include `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file to use the Python 3-style division in Python 2.x.

Assuming you don't use the `__future__` solution, you will also want to write your `R = A / P` as e.g. `R = float(A) / P` because otherwise, if `A` and `P` are both integers, `R` will also be an integer.